# Type constraints for static methods

Tags: f#

I am using OpenTK with its math library but unfortunately there is no generic interface for the vector classes. For example Vector2 ,3 and 4 all have the same static method `SizeInBytes` http://www.opentk.com/files/doc/struct_open_t_k_1_1_vector3.html#ae7cbee02af524095ee72226d842c6892

Now I could just overload tons of different constructors but I think it should be possible to solve this via type constraints.

I was reading though http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233203.aspx and I found this

```
type Class4<'T when 'T : (static member staticMethod1 : unit -> 'T) > =
    class end
```

Now I have tried it by myself but I can't get the syntax right.

```
type Foo<'T when 'T: (static member SizeInBytes: unit -> int)>(data: 'T []) =
   member this.GetBytes() = 'T.SizeInBytes() 

let f = Foo([|new Vector3(1.0f,1.0f,1.0f)|])
f.GetBytes()
```

Can you spot the problem?

Edit:
VS2012 complains about this line `'T.SizeInBytes() //Unexpected symbol or expression` and `T.SizeInBytes()` doesn't work either.

Edit2:

I made an example that doesn't involve an external library

```
type Bar() = 
    static member Print() = printf "Hello Foo"

type Foo<'T when 'T: (static member Print: unit -> unit)>(data: 'T []) =
   member this.Print() = 'T.Print()

let b1 = Bar()
let f = Foo([|b1|])
f.Print()
```

Comment: Can you add details of what goes wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The correct syntax for calling things which are guaranteed by member constraints is a bit obscure:

```
type Foo< ^T when ^T: (static member SizeInBytes: unit -> int)>(data: ^T []) =
   member inline this.GetBytes() =
       (^T : (static member SizeInBytes : unit -> int) ())
```

Note that `'T` has to be changed to a "statically resolved type variable" `^T` - see the Glossary in the [F# spec](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/cambridge/projects/fsharp/manual/spec.html).

You can't call members specified by constraints on normal type variables, because that's not supported by the .NET framework, so F# has to compile them away. It's a syntax error if we try to use `'T` in `GetBytes` instead.

I think the MSDN documentation is being a bit misleading by giving an example with `'T`, because although you can write the type they give, you could never use the constraint.

If you look at the IL code for the `Class4` sample, the constraint is actually gone:

```
.class nested public auto ansi serializable Class4`1<T>
    extends [mscorlib]System.Object
```

which makes sense because the member constraint has to be removed for .NET. The same is true for `type Foo` with the `^T` type variable.

Note also that in common with all `inline` F# functions, you can only call it statically from F# code, so that the compiler can inline the definition at the call site.

It will throw an exception if you try to call it from C# code, or via reflection. If you try, your code will fail at runtime.

Generally working with F# constraints that aren't supported by .NET is a tricky business, so I'd steer clear if at all possible.

EDITED: I've substantially updated my original answer which incorrectly said this wasn't possible, in light of (a) my further experiments (b) Gene Belitski's answer and (c) idjarn's comment that `inline` functions always get compiled to IL that throws an exception.

Comment: All `inline` functions compile to IL throwing that exception, for when languages other than F# try to call them. As long as the function is called from F# it will work fine (inline function code is stored in metadata rather than IL).

Comment: Thanks - I hadn't realised this happens before. I wonder why the compiler doesn't just omit them completely, seems less friendly to make callers think they can do it and then throw at runtime.

Answer (score 4):

Worked for me just fine using [hat notation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd548046.aspx):

```
type Bar() =
    static member SizeInBytes() = 42

type Foo< ^T when ^T: (static member SizeInBytes: unit -> int)>(data: ^T []) =
    member inline this.GetBytes () = (^T : (static member SizeInBytes : unit -> int) ())

let result = (Foo([|Bar()|]).GetBytes())
```

---

```
val result : int = 42
```

Comment: So it does (I think I got distracted by the fact that <^ without the space causes a parse error) - though it has the same problem I mentioned in my answer that the compiled method just throws an exception.

Comment: No, it **works fine** in compiled form too! Did you try to look at IL after switching to `^T`? I guess you didn't.

Comment: Yes, I did look at the IL after switching before I made that comment. I mean that if you tried to call it in a situation where the F# compiler hasn't inlined the use, then it would throw.

Comment: Just tested by calling it from a C# project and it does indeed throw.

Comment: Agree that it won't work in scenarios where F# compiler cannot `inline`.